# How to update Phone number for call initiation while reading data from CSV file

Tags: java, android, file

I am trying to make an auto calling app that would read phone number from a csv file and call them one by one, but it is only able to call the first number and the command never reach the second number though I'm able to print the all the  numbers from csv file to log

I have used a input stream method followed by buffer reader

```
  File inputfile = new File(filepath);
           try {
                 InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputfile);
                  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
                    InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        try {
            String csvLine;
            while ((csvLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] ids = csvLine.split(",");

                try
                {
                    Log.e("Column 1 ", "" + ids[0]);

                    for (String id : ids) {
                        number = id;
                        initiatecall();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("Unknown ", e.toString());
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("unknown", e.toString());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The command is calling only the first number in csv file and it never call the subsequent numbers

Comment: initiatecall() method should be hanging, running infinitely and not returning back. Chk tht

Comment: take a look at that log, make sure the splitting of the file is correct, and, as the comment above states, check if that call hangs forever...